# Is it possible to print a HTML entity in JS or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, entity

I would like to know if it is possible to print a html entity in JavaScript or PHP.

Example :

`console.log("&#55;");`

Whenever i try, it converts `&#55;` into 7 instead of showing the entity number.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SJKrP/ - both turn up as `&#55;` in my firefox console.. might depend on what console you are using?

Comment: turns up as &#55; in my google chrome console..

Comment: could try using the `htmlentities()` or `html_entity_decode()` functions in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php (edit - before I get flamed he did say 'or PHP' in title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to encode the ampersand for that to work. Try the following and see how it works:

```
console.log('&amp;#55;');
```

Answer (score 0):

A PHP solution would be -apart from simply echoing it (might be a serverside setting)- the following.

```
   echo '&#49;&#51;&#51;&#55;'; //Outputs 1337 on my server.

   $string = '&#49;&#51;&#51;&#55;';
   $entities = htmlentities($string); 
   echo $entities; //Outputs &#49;&#51;&#51;&#55;

   $decode = html_entity_decode($entities);
   echo $decode; //Outputs 1337
```