# Does typer.js allow ascii characters?

Tags: html

Comma is used as the delimiter in [typer.js](https://steven.codes/typerjs/). I am trying to use the ascii code of `&#44;` for a comma but to no avail.. A blank space appears.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/straversi/pen/yrLvmw

```html
<h1>
  It was <span
    class="typer"
    id="some-id"
    data-words="dark&#44;,stormy&#44;,night&#44;"
    data-delay="100"
    data-colors="#08605F,#177E89,purple">
  </span>
  <span style="font-size:1.2em;vertical-align:middle;" class="cursor" data-cursorDisplay="|" data-owner="some-id"></span>
</h1>
<button class="typer-stop" data-owner="some-id">Stop</button>
<button class="typer-start" data-owner="some-id">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print a comma.. you need to encode it :)

```html
<h1>
  It was <span
    class="typer"
    id="some-id"
    data-words="&amp;#44;.,dark.,stormy.,night."
    data-delay="100"
    data-colors="#08605F,#177E89,purple">
  </span>
  <span style="font-size:1.2em;vertical-align:middle;" class="cursor" data-cursorDisplay="|" data-owner="some-id"></span>
</h1>
<button class="typer-stop" data-owner="some-id">Stop</button>
<button class="typer-start" data-owner="some-id">Start</button>
```

A comma encoded: `&amp;#44;`

Some common symbols as encoded: [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Read this: [Is it possible to print a HTML entity in JS or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684868/11700321)

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: This [behaviour](https://codepen.io/bradscanvas/pen/mddPpKO) is now happening ....? @ECG

Comment: Wow, so I've been to hell and back. None of the comma's want to work correctly except this one? `data-words="&#xff0c;."` https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/index.htm

Comment: So weird.. I tried every other comma variation I could find in every ASCII / Unicode table ever.. :S